# Use Stream to populate TextEditingController in flutter app

Tags: flutter, stream, flutter-streambuilder

I can't seem to pass a QuerySnapshot from one class to another without losing the Snapshot so I am trying to find a work around ([see my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68536236/passing-querysnapshot-data-to-tabview-so-i-can-access-it-in-pages-in-each-tab/68540843?noredirect=1#comment121142246_68540843)). I am trying to pull the data again by using a StreamBuilder.

```
StreamBuilder (
        stream: _db.collection('agency').doc(globals.agencyId).
        collection('trxns').doc(globals.currentTrxnId).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, trxnSnapshot) {  <<<< ERROR 1
        if (trxnSnapshot.hasData) {
          var outPut = trxnSnapshot.data();  <<<< ERROR 2
          clientFNameController.text = trxnSnapshot.data.data['clientFName'] ?? ""; <<<< ERROR 3
        }
)
```

I am getting some errors.

1. The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
   I have tried adding "?" and "!" but it is not working.
2. Found this line of code in a post but I am not sure how to get the data from the snapshot.
3. This error will be fixed after #2 is fixed.

These should be easy fixes but I'm not sure how to do it.

**EDIT** I tried adding type casting as shown below but I get new errors.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> (
        stream: _db.collection('agency').doc(globals.agencyId).
        collection('trxns').doc(globals.currentTrxnId).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, trxnSnapshot) {
          if (trxnSnapshot.hasData) {
            var outPut = (trxnSnapshot.data() as QueryDocumentSnapshot);
                        clientFNameController.text = trxnSnapshot.data.data['clientFName'] ?? "";
          }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if the snapshot you are receiving has any data. If not, it is impossible to call `trxnSnapshot.data()`

Try this:

```
StreamBuilder (
        stream: _db.collection('agency').doc(globals.agencyId).
        collection('trxns').doc(globals.currentTrxnId).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, trxnSnapshot) {
          if(trxnSnapshot.hasData){  
            var outPut = trxnSnapshot.data();  
            clientFNameController.text = trxnSnapshot.data.data['clientFName'] ?? "";
       } else {
            print("Do something, maybe show a loading widget");
    }
          
)
```

Comment: Thanks @AlanCesar for you response but I still have the errors. They are connected with null safety. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?